# JSch ChannelSftp.put method RESUME mode

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I had a question about **RESUME** mode of `ChannelSftp.put()` method of JSch.

While transferring file, if file already exists on the server with the same name but different date modified and size (larger than existing) i.e. newer version of the file and I run the `put()` method with **RESUME** mode then will it add the difference of bytes between the two files to the file existing on server or overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the target remote file exists already and is larger than the source local file, `ChannelSftp.put` throws an exception:

  ```
  long skip=0;
  if(mode==RESUME || mode==APPEND){
      try{
        SftpATTRS attr=_stat(dstb);
        skip=attr.getSize();
      }
      catch(Exception eee){
      }
  }
  if(mode==RESUME && skip>0){
      long skipped=src.skip(skip);
      if(skipped<skip){
        throw new SftpException(SSH_FX_FAILURE, "failed to resume for "+dst);
      }
  }
  ```
- Modification time is not considered at all.

---

All in all, it's up to you to decide if it makes sense to resume the transfer. The `RESUME` flag should be used only, when you already know that the transfer can be resumed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, the exception is also thrown when the remote file is smaller and the source file is bigger?

Comment: No, of course not. Why would it? When the remote file is smaller and the source file is bigger, that's exact situation in which you want to use the `RESUME` mode.

Comment: Ok. One last question, what is the default mode if I don't pass any parameter to the put command i.e. put(new FileInputStream, String src, String dest)

Comment: There's no overload of `put` with these arguments. Though all overloads of `put` that lack `mode` argument use `OVERWRITE` mode (no suprise).